# No logro instalar opencv para python 3.9

Tags: python, cmd, opencv, pip, cv2

Cuando uso pip para instalar opencv me aparece esto

```
C:\Users\usuario>pip install opencv-contrib-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (4.4.0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.19.4)
```

Pero al correr un codigo de python importando opencv (import cv2 as cv) me da un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo no usar una version tan reciente de python ya que vas a tener esos bugs.

Comment: Usas anaconda? Si lo usas, instalalo desde anaconda comand ahi ya no te dara problemas

Answer (score 1):

El problema es de `Numpy` que es usado por `OpenCV` y no lo tienes actualizado, ejecuta el siguiente comando para actualizarlo:

```
pip install -U numpy
```